# Where are Android Emulator Images Stored?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-file

On the emulator, I downloaded an image from Google. I can find the image on the emulator, but I have no idea what the file location of the image is. To debug my app I need to know where that image is. How can I get the full path of the image?

Comment: Remember after you download the SDK you'll have to create AVD for each API level http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This here seems to work for me:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
String myJpgPath = path + "/Download/dog-best-friend-1.jpg";
```

Answer (score 79):

From the [AVD documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds-cmdline.html):

> By default, the android tool creates the AVD directory inside `~/.android/avd/` (on Linux/Mac), `C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\.android\` on Windows XP, and `C:\Users\<user>\.android\` on Windows 7 and Vista.

Update (2020-02-22): This wording isn’t on the current documentation page anymore, but the location appears to be the same (`C:\Users\<user>\.android\`) on Windows 8 and 10.

Comment: I can not find the image, I am trying to do this: 
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/mnt/dog-best-friend-1.jpg");

Answer (score 14):

Not obvious thing in official documentation

[image: Maybe this?]

Comment: Oh my God, finally the answer I've been looking for! I've opened the emulator files directory through AVD manager (the way many people advised), but there are just a few directories and files, it never helped. Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

The system images are downloaded in 
[ {android_version_home_dir}/sdk/system-images/{android-version-number}/system.img> ]

and the avd are created in C:\Users\.android\avd\ (windows) or ~/.android/avd/ (linux/mac)

Answer (score 4):

On windows:-> `C:\Users\yourUser\Documents\AndroidStudio\DeviceExplorer\Pixel_2_API_30 [emulator-5554]\data\data\com.yourpackage\files`

After the emulator name, you can choose the path in your code.

Comment: Nice! Needed this

Answer (score 2):

If your image is stored on your emulator then you can find that image using file Explore

First Start your Emulator then:

Open your File Explorer and go to `mnt/sdcard/Download` you will find your image here if its downloaded.

To open file explore in Eclipse : `window/show view/other/File Explore`

Answer (score 2):

To find the exact path open the emulator go to Photos then click on a photo (if there is any) then click on i (for info). There you can see the exact path on your device.To access these files dynamicly try:

```
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    String pathPhotos = path2 +"/Download";
    File[] fileArr = new File(pathPhotos).listFiles();

    for(int i = 0; i < fileArr.length; i++) {
        Log.d("fileName12", " " + fileArr[i].getPath());
    }
```

In case listFiles returns null you have to add:
uses-permission *android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
And change the settings on the Emulator -> settings -> Apps -> App Permissions -> storage -> your app name -> switch on

Answer (score 2):

In Windows ---> C:\Documents and Settings<user>.android\

Answer (score 0):

i found it at (Windows 10):
C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).