# How can I use the system image downloaded from IDM in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I've downloaded system image for Nougat (7.0) version in Android Studio, but during the middle, my bill has gone so the download stopped. However it said download complete. So,I clicked finish. Then I download the same system image by copying URL to IDM, where I finished the download completely. So, instead of the system image that I've download in Android Studio, I want to use the system image from IDM. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13095728/4762767

Comment: I didn't download it on the emulator, I download it from IDM. I know the file location but I don't know how to use it in the Android Studio. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SHORT AND EASY PROCESS:**

In the avd choose the system image you have downloaded and start downloading it in Android Studio. But as soon as the download starts cancel it. This will result in the creation of the folder in which the image will be copied by Android Studio. Now go to your Android SDK directory. Then find the folder system-images but then you will have to find **.installer** in the directories. Delete it and paste the extracted android system image. Restart your Android Studio.  That's it.

**LENGHTY PROCESS:**

Go to your Android SDK directory. Then find the folder system-images. Then create a folder but be very careful in naming it. The API of the android system image should be its name. Then again create a folder and name it ( The type of system-image ) then if its 86x then again create a folder and name it 86x. Now here extract your files.

In my case the the place where the img files are, is:
E:\Android_SDK\system-images\android-28\google_apis_playstore\x86

[An image which might help you.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VugZ.png)