# Photo files in android emulator

Tags: android

I'm trying to write an app, that would load a video file. I'm trying to figure out where to put the video file so that I can load it. I'm looking at this thread:

[Where are Android Emulator Image Stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13095718/where-are-android-emulator-image-stored)

So I used the emulator, to take an image with its camera. I find the image location in the emulator:
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20211021_115000.jpg

I try to find the file

```
$ cd .android
$ ls
adbkey              cache
adbkey.pub          debug.keystore
analytics.settings      debug.keystore.lock
avd             emu-last-feature-flags.protobuf
breakpad            emu-update-last-check.ini
build-cache         maps.key
build-cache.lock        modem-nv-ram-5554
$ find . -name IMG_20211021_115000.jpg
$
```

My question is where is it stored?

Comment: "I try to find the file" -- you appear to be looking on your development machine. The image is not a file on your development machine. It is a file inside of the emulator's disk image.

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestions on how I can upload a video file to the  emulators image? I can use google drive and share.

Comment: "Any suggestions on how I can upload a video file to the emulators image?" -- [drag and drop works](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#installadd). So does Device File Explorer in Android Studio and `adb push`.